# Regularizing a curve with an isolated singularity

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose $\gamma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth curve which is regular everywhere except at an isolated point: $\gamma'(t_0) = 0$. Are there general conditions for which we can find a *regular* curve  $\tilde\gamma$ satisfying the property that the image of $\tilde\gamma$ is equal to the image of $\gamma$? If so, are there general constructive arguments to produce $\tilde\gamma$ from $\gamma$? (Actually what I really need is to construct such a regularization locally.)

In principle this construction seems like it should be possible sometimes by combining some sort of continuity-of-derivatives argument across the singular point with some rescaling of the tangent vectors, but it feels difficult to come up with an actual example. It seems that if such a construction does exist, it will depend on how quickly the curve goes singular, so I will need control over higher-order derivatives of $\gamma$ to produce a regularization. On the other hand, it is easy to come up with nonexamples, like the cusp $t\mapsto(t^2,t^3)$.

Maybe I'm silly and there's an easy obstruction to my question, but I feel like classical differential geometry texts tend to avoid curves that aren't regular.

Comment: What's necessary and sufficient is that the curve be a $1$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin why?

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I'll write my response as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, a necessary and sufficient condition for there to be a (local) regular parameterization is that the curve be a $1$-dimensional manifold (perhaps with boundary).

If you have a $1$-manifold, then any local parametrization (inverse of a chart) is a local diffeomorphism from an interval in $\Bbb R$ to the curve, and this is by definition a regular parametrization.

Conversely, if we have a regular parametrization $\tilde\gamma$, then that gives you the local diffeomorphism with an interval in $\Bbb R$, and hence the structure of $1$-manifold. (If you prefer to have local charts, take the inverse mapping of the parametrization.)